# Adding another property with Key Value in an object

Tags: javascript

I am sorry if this question already asked but i guess it confusing so i want to know how to add a property in an object which is not defined in the object.

I want to add a property name: 'something' in a nested objects.

```
let cars = {
  passengers: null,
  engine: {
  yearBuilt: 2002,
  model: "25481 AL"
  }
```

now it has two properties passengers and engine. What i want is to add another property "name" in passengers and log it in an array with ['Alex', 'Mark']

What i tried:

```
cars.passengers = [{name: 'Alex'}]; //Output is like this [ { name: 'Alex' } ],
```

and when i add a square bracket notation in Alex only the output will be 
    name: [Object] }

```
cars.passengers = [{name: 'Alex'}]; //Output is like this [ { name: ['Alex'] } ] //Output is like { passengers: [ { name: [Object] } ]
```

code:

```
let newData = cars.passengers = [{name: ['Alex']}];
```

why its not showing in an array.? and how to do that .?

Comment: You said yourself that the output shows an array, what exactly is your question?: //Output is like this [ { name: 'Alex' } ],

Comment: @DimitriL. //Output should be like this 
 {name: ['Alex'] }

not like this 

 [ { name: 'Alex' } ]

Comment: cars.passengers = {name: ['Alex'] }

Comment: lol xD yes Thanks.. It Works

Comment: If you wanted that value why not use that value instead adding the value you didn't want?

Comment: Just to clarify: `[]` this is an array, `{}` this is an object.

Comment: i have updated it as answer. Please mark it as correct so someone might find it useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript objects vs arrays vs JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764208/javascript-objects-vs-arrays-vs-json)

Comment: @DimitriL. yes Thanks but  the confusion was what if i want to add another object in object which is already defined and the property would be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try

```
cars.passengers = {name: ['Alex'] }
```