# Why is headers not in the Object.keys for the request object in node?

Tags: node.js

I see this when use node to inspect the request object of an incoming http request: `Object.keys(req)` contains `rawHeaders` but not `headers`.

Can someone point to the documentation on why `headers` is not in the list of keys?

`rawHeaders` seems to be an array of strings while `headers` is an object. See [javascript objects vs arrays vs JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764208/javascript-objects-vs-arrays-vs-json)

```
DEBUG: req: keys: _readableState,_events,_eventsCount,_maxListeners,socket,httpVersionMajor,httpVersionMinor,httpVersion,complete,rawHeaders,rawTrailers,aborted,upgrade,url,method,statusCode,statusMessage,client,_consuming,_dumped,next,baseUrl,originalUrl,_parsedUrl,params,query,res,body,route
```

`req.rawHeaders`:

```
DEBUG: req: rawheaders: STRINGIFY: ["host","localhost:5001","connection","keep-alive","pragma","no-cache","cache-control","no-cache","sec-ch-ua","\"Not_A Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"120\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"120\"","sec-ch-ua-mobile","?0","sec-ch-ua-platform","\"Linux\"","dnt","1","upgrade-insecure-requests","1","user-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7","sec-fetch-site","same-origin","sec-fetch-mode","navigate","sec-fetch-user","?1","sec-fetch-dest","document","accept-encoding","gzip, deflate, br","accept-language","en-US,en;q=0.9,it-IT;q=0.8,it;q=0.7","cookie","amp-access=amp-7JjY8O_xkojgphlXHw-5rg; _ga=GA1.1.1937988494.1707261141; _ga_EPYLVLZHVN=GS1.1.1707261141.1.1.1707261271.0.0.0"]
```

`req.headers`:

```
 DEBUG: req: headers: {"host":"localhost:5001","connection":"keep-alive","pragma":"no-cache","cache-control":"no-cache","sec-ch-ua":"\"Not_A Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"120\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"120\"","sec-ch-ua-mobile":"?0","sec-ch-ua-platform":"\"Linux\"","dnt":"1","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7","sec-fetch-site":"same-origin","sec-fetch-mode":"navigate","sec-fetch-user":"?1","sec-fetch-dest":"document","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9,it-IT;q=0.8,it;q=0.7","cookie":"amp-access=amp-7JjY8O_xkojgphlXHw-5rg; _ga=GA1.1.1937988494.1707261141; _ga_EPYLVLZHVN=GS1.1.1707261141.1.1.1707261271.0.0.0"}
```

Notice the format of `headers` is very different. This is using Node v16.15.1.

Comment: [_"The `Object.keys()` static method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property names"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) - `headers` is clearly string-keyed, so not enumerable and/or own.

Answer (score 2):

`rawHeaders` is property of Request object, but `headers` is defined in parent class  `http.IncomingMessage` so it is not enumerable property. You can still see it, but not by using `Object.keys`.

[Here is an example how to list non-enumerable properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object)