# How is req.headers accessible in an Express app?

Tags: javascript, express

When I inspect the `req` object in an Express app, I do not see a `headers` property anywhere. So how does the app retrieve its value?

Steps to reproduce:

1. In the Terminal, prepare an Express project folder:

   ```
   mkdir test && cd test && npm init -y && npm i express
   ```
2. Create a bare-bones server script:

   ```
   touch server.js && cat << 'EOF' > server.js  
   const { inspect } = require('util')  
   const PORT = 3333

   const express = require('express')  
   const app = express()

   app.get('/', (req, res) => {  
     const message = `<pre>  
   <b>req.headers:</b>  
   ${inspect(req.headers)}

   <b>req:</b>   
   ${inspect(req)}  
   </pre>`

     res.send(message)  
   })


   app.listen(PORT, () => {  
     console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);  
   })  
   EOF
   ```
3. Start the server:

   ```
   node server.js
   ```
4. Click on the link to http://localhost:3333 in the Terminal
5. Inspect the output in the browser

According to the first part of the output, `req.headers` definitely exists. In my case, I see an object that starts like this:

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3333',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 ...',
  ...
}
```

In the second part, the explicit listing of the `req` object shows that `headers` is nowhere to be found.

In `req` there *is* an entry for `rawHeaders` which is an array where the items alternate between keys and values, where the words used in the keys start with uppercase letters.

```
[
  'Host',
  'localhost:3333',
  'User-Agent',
  'Mozilla/5.0 ...',
  ...
]
```

There *is also* an entry for `[Symbol(kHeaders)]` which is an object where the words used as the keys start with lowercase letters, just like in `req.headers`:

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3333',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 ...'
  ...
}
```

It looks like this is what is being delivered as `req.headers`.

What is the JavaScript engine doing that makes this happen?

How could I write that would simulate the way `req` behaves? That is: how can I create an object which does *not* have a `headers` key, but which returns a value when `myObject.headers` is accessed?

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/78028563/3001761, basically. Read https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options to see your options.